# Como puedo ejecutar 2 procemientos almacenados que cumplen la funcion de seleccionar en SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Estos son mis procedimientos

```
exec select_cupos2
exec select_cupos
```

Y cuando ejecuto los 2 a la vez, nunca logra mostrar resultados, solo sale cargando, y cuando para la ejecución, el procedimeinto `exec select_cupos` funciona perfectamente, menos esta de aquí `exec select_cupos2`
habrá una forma de poder ejecutar los dos y que muestren sus resultados al mismo tiempo?

Comment: Lo que quieres es mostrar los resultados de ambos procedimientos en el mismo resultset como una especie de union?

Comment: Gracias, ya lo solucione, modificando mas el procedimiento almacenado+

Answer (score 0):

Pruebe de esta manera:

exec select_cupos2 
Go
exec select_cupos
Go

Sombreas ambos procedimientos y los ejecutas , debe de mostrarte el resultado de ambos.